# Pulling data from SQL Server via powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Why does this work:

```
param($destserver, $destDB)
$destserver = "CCIIT23"
$destDB = "SSIMS_Prod"
$Servers = "CCIIT23"
$CounterList = "\Memory\Available MBytes", "\Memory\Page Faults/sec", "\Memory\Pages/sec"
$Servers | Foreach-Object { 
$Serv = $_; $CounterList | Foreach-Object { 
    Get-Counter -Computer $Serv -Counter $_ -SampleInterval 1
    }
}
```

and this not work?

```
param($destserver, $destDB)
$destserver = "CCIIT23"
$destDB = "SSIMS_Prod"
$Servers = Get-SqlData $destserver $destDb "Select ServerName From ServerNames"
$CounterList = Get-SqlData $destserver $destDb "Select Counter From MemoryCounterList"
$Servers | Foreach-Object { 
$Serv = $_; $CounterList | Foreach-Object { 
    Get-Counter -Computer $Serv -Counter $_ -SampleInterval 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? What is the Get-SqlData function doing? Where is that defined?

Comment: FYI: `Get-SqlData` is not a built-in command to PowerShell. It looks like there is a third-party project called "SQL PSX" that has a function named that, however it's very possible that it could be coming from something even different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess here that you're using `Get-SqlData` from the module `SQL PSX`.  If you had shown some effort, you might have read this

> The Get-SqlData function executes a query and returns an array of
>   System.Data.DataRow.

Source: [Get-SqlData](http://sqlpsx.appspot.com/Get-SqlData.htm)

And a `DataRow` is NOT a string, but an object. By visiting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you would find an example of how to use a `DataRow` object: `row["ColumnName"]`

Which means you should try using

```
$Serv = $_["ServerName"]   #You may need to use $_["ServerName"].ToString()  .  $_.Servername might also work
```

and

```
Get-Counter -Computer $Serv -Counter ($_["Counter"]) -SampleInterval 1
```

I don't have a sql server to test against, but this should get you going. A google search might lead you to another forum post like this which shows how to loop through the resultsets if `Foreach-Object` doesn't work:

http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/7980.aspx

Everyone's welcome to ask questions here, but please show some effort or your question will be closed and downvoted.